# Unable To Import Pygame After Pip Install

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I installed pygame through pip. I know for a fact it is there, as I have seen the file labeled 'pygame' in the file explorer. However Python does not agree with me that it is certainly there.

What makes this odd is that i've installed pygame using pip before on a different user, it worked fine, and i did nothing differently this time.

> > > import pygame
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import pygame
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: Have you installed the pygame version that is compatible with your Python version? Also, if you are using a virtualenvironment, make sure pygame is actually installed in the virtual environment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual environment. It seems that you are not using the environment where you have installed pygame. If you are using Anaconda, the environment is specified in parentheses. You can activate your environment using:
`conda activate <conda environment name here>`

Hope this works!